# create system call that prints run queue tasks pids

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a system call that would be something like that :

```
print_tasks(int cpu_x);
```

which  prints the pids of all task that are in runquque of cpu_x.

how do I iterate over all of them? and should I hold **runqueue lock** while doing so?

Comment: What have you tried this far? It's usually expected to show some effort in terms of actual code in the question because SO is not a free programming service.

Comment: @SamiLaine I saw that you can do that with list_for_each_safe macro, and &init_task, though im not sure how to get init_task of a specific cpu? is that the right direction of solving this?